# image resizing in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was looking for an image resizing service in AWS and found this one ( Seems to be the most popular).

[image]

I installed it correctly

[image]

But I can't find any examples of how to use it.

The github repo was not very helpful:

https://github.com/cagataygurturk/image-resizer-service

Does anybody have experience with it or something similar I can use?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a turnkey solution that doesn't require any work, you might consider a service like https://imgix.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of this service is to dynamically resize and serve images that already exist in your S3 bucket.

The idea is that your web client can then request a specific image. For example the image at `s3://mybucket/cats/siamese.jpg` can be requested by making an API call to your deployed API Gateway endpoint at `https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/cats/siamese.jpg`.

The resize feature is triggered when the client includes width and height query parameters, for example: [https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/cats/siamese.jpg?width=960&height=480`](https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/cats/siamese.jpg?width=960&height=480%60)

It's not a general purpose "send me an image and I will resize it" kind of service.